# What is the difference in usage of connection vs session for Flask application which uses SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask application which uses SQLAlchemy to talk to the database. For a single request application performs  multiple dml operations following transaction as a single unit of work. The incoming request decides which database to connect as there are one database per user for certain scenarios. Because of this db per user complexity and often the sql queries issued are complex, we are not using SQLAlchemy ORM or Flask-SQLAlchemy

**How do I choose between using connection vs session in the context of a webapp?**

Both connection and session helps to achieve the transactional behaviour. SQLalchemy docs recommend using connections for executing textual sql.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#
Recommended way of using a conenction and transaction is the following.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test")
connection = engine.connect()
trans = connection.begin()
connection.execute("insert into x (a, b) values (1, 2)")
trans.commit()
```

But the docs also say that both connection and transactions are not thread safe.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Transaction.

**If so, what are the scenarios where a connection object is useful?**

When it comes to sessions, Scoped sessions provided by sqlalchemy is thread safe and seems like a solution for this problem.
But sessions dont support the nested transaction behaviour unlike connection https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#nesting-of-transaction-blocks.

I have gone through many answers in stackoverflow. But I didn't find any answers the difference between connection and session w.r.t thread safety in web apps.

Comment: when your are running `connection = engine.connect()`. It means you are getting on connection object from connection pool. so connection objects are thread safe.

Comment: But the doc says transaction and connection objects are not thread safe. Hence , I thought they can't be used in a multithreaded web app?

Comment: please go through the locks and transaction in mysql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-transaction-model.html.      if you really want only one connection to update the row then you need to have an write lock on that row. Here is one live example of transactions in mysql https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCcV2IAlafA

Comment: @pavan connections are not thread-safe, i.e. 2 threads must not concurrently operate on the same checked out connection.